# CLRS example big Omega

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

(1/2) n<sup>2</sup> - 3n = Ω(n<sup>2</sup>)

To demonstrate it the author choose the values c=(1/4) and n0=7 but I don't understand why. I know the definition of big Theta but I don't know yet how to apply it.

Comment: Are you trying to prove big omega or big theta?  Your equation uses big omega.

Comment: It makes sense you wouldn't understand, because `n^2 / 2 - 3 * n >= n^2 / 4, ∀ n > 7` is false. Try solving for n. [Spoiler](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+n%5E2+%2F+2+-+3+*+n+%3E%3D+n%5E2+%2F+4+for+n).